# Why i am getting " org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed "

Tags: spring, jsp

[image: Generating Exception]

this is a pojo Class

**CustomerModel.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
public class CustomerModel
{   
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name="ID")
  private int CustomerID;

  @Column(name="First_Name")
  private String customerFName;

  @Column(name="Last_Name")
  private String customerLName;

  @Column(name="Email")
  private String customerEmail;

  @Column(name="Password")
  private String customerPassword;
 }
```

This is my dao class where i am searching customer in the database if it is found then show this is a valid user else must show invalid credentials.

**customerDao.java**

```
  @Transactional
  @Repository
  public class CustomerDao implements custDaoInterface {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public boolean checkLogin(String custEmail, String custPassword) 
   {
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     System.out.println("In Check Login");
     boolean userFound= false;

     String sql="from CustomerModel where Email=? and Password=?";
     Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
     query.setParameter(0,custEmail);
     query.setParameter(1,custPassword);
     List list = query.list();

     if((list!=null) && (list.size()>0))
     {
         userFound= true;
     }
     session.close();
     return userFound;
    }
   }
```

why i am getting this exception.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Also: You do not need to close the session - that is done automatically with @Transactional.